# Only assign values to entries relevant to condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, window-functions

I have the following code

```
with my_table (id, student, category, score)
as (values 
(1, 'Alex', 'A', 11),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 4),
(3, 'Bill', 'A', 81),
(4, 'Bill', 'B', 1),
(5, 'Bill', 'D', 22),
(6, 'Carl', 'C', 5),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 10)
)

select
  id, student, category, score,
  case when 
         max(score) filter (where category in ('A', 'B', 'C')) over (partition by student) >
         min(score) filter (where category = 'D') over (partition by student)
      then 'Review'
      else 'Pass'
  end as result
from my_table
order by student, id
```

which outputs

```
id  student   category    score   conclusion
1    Alex     A           11       Review
2    Alex     D           4        Review
3    Bill     A           81       Review
4    Bill     B           1        Review
5    Bill     D           22       Review
6    Carl     C           5        Pass
7    Carl     D           10       Pass
```

How can I edit it so only the entries where either A, B, or C are larger than D are assigned 'Review' to them. So in this case, the desired output would be:

```
id  student   category    score   conclusion
1    Alex     A           11       Review
2    Alex     D           4        Review
3    Bill     A           81       Review
4    Bill     B           1        Pass
5    Bill     D           22       Review
6    Carl     C           5        Pass
7    Carl     D           10       Pass
```

For Bill, A>D so Review is assigned to it; B<D so Pass is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

From your logic, you can try to use subquery to get `count` then compare

```
with my_table (id, student, category, score)
as (values 
(1, 'Alex', 'A', 11),
(2, 'Alex', 'D', 4),
(3, 'Bill', 'A', 81),
(4, 'Bill', 'B', 1),
(5, 'Bill', 'D', 22),
(6, 'Carl', 'C', 5),
(7, 'Carl', 'D', 10)
)
SELECT  id, student, category, score,
       CASE WHEN 
        COUNT(*) filter (where D_Score<score) over (partition by student) = 0 OR score < D_Score 
        THEN 'Pass'
        ELSE 'Review' END
FROM (
    SELECT *,
       min(score) filter (where category = 'D') over (partition by student) D_Score
    FROM my_table
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=71fdccb381f23d64bb1d83f52eb2aba5)